# Keep GCC from altering size of structs (.BMP file header)

Tags: c, gcc, struct, bmp

I'm currently trying to create a .BMP file. The BMP header is, by my definition, 54 bytes long. The code compiles and everything, but when trying to open the file, I get a "incorrect header format" error.

If I do a sizeof(structtype) I get 56 bytes instead of the defined 54 - and if I initialize a struct with values, then do a sizeof(newStruct), I get 8 bytes. Since I need the exact 54 bytes to be written into the file, this is terrible.

Is there a way to keep the GCC from altering the struct size this way?

Here's the definition of the structs:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint16_t typeSignature; // = "BM"
  uint32_t filesize;     //filesize in Bytes
  uint32_t reserved;     // = 0 for this program
  uint32_t headerOffset; // = 54
} BmpFileHeader;

typedef struct
{
  uint32_t infoHeaderSize;    //size of header in byte. ( = 40)
  uint32_t Width;             //width of file in pixels
  uint32_t Height;            // height of file in pixels

  uint16_t Colors;       //colorbits per pixel (24 for 3byte RGB)
  uint16_t bitsPerPixel;
  uint32_t Compression;       //compression mode; 0 for uncompressed.
  uint32_t SizeImg;         //if biCompress = 0, =0. Else: filesize.

  uint32_t xPelsPerMeter;     // for output device;
  uint32_t yPelsPerMeter;     // 0 for this program

  uint32_t ColorsUsed;      // Colours used; = 0 for all
  uint32_t ColorsImportant; // num. of used colours, 0 for all
} BmpInfoHeader;

typedef struct
{
  BmpFileHeader fileheader;
  BmpInfoHeader infoheader;
} bitmapHead; // sizeof = 56
```

and here the function which initializes a new Header:

```
bitmapHead* assembleHeader(int compCount)
{
  bitmapHead* newHeader = (bitmapHead*) calloc(1, 54);  
  newHeader->fileheader.typeSignature = 0x4D42;
  newHeader->fileheader.filesize = (compCount*100*51*3 + 54);
  newHeader->fileheader.reserved = 0;
  newHeader->fileheader.headerOffset = 54;


  newHeader->infoheader.infoHeaderSize = 40;
  newHeader->infoheader.Width = 100*compCount;
  newHeader->infoheader.Height = 51;
  newHeader->infoheader.Colors = 1; 
  newHeader->infoheader.bitsPerPixel = 21;
  newHeader->infoheader.Compression = 0;
  newHeader->infoheader.SizeImg = compCount*100*51*3;
  newHeader->infoheader.xPelsPerMeter = 0;
  newHeader->infoheader.yPelsPerMeter = 0;
  newHeader->infoheader.ColorsUsed = 0;
  newHeader->infoheader.ColorsImportant = 0;
  printf("%lu \n", sizeof(newHeader)); // This gives me 8. 
  return newHeader;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a padding issue: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

Comment: this pair of lines: uint16_t typeSignature; // = "BM"
  uint32_t filesize;     //filesize in Bytes will get a 2 byte padding between them.  One way to get around that is to use the pack pragma.  Another way is to define each field as a series of bytes and insert the data byte by byte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a case of "don't do that then."  Specifically, never attempt to lay out a C `struct` which matches a byte pattern defined by an external specification.  The C standard is not interested in cooperating with this, and while *some* compilers attempt to make it sort-of possible, it's more trouble than it's worth.  (Read up on Ada representation clauses, if you're interested in seeing what a language that takes this problem seriously looks like.)

You can define a `struct` to represent the BMP header *in memory*, but the thing you read from/write to disk should be an array of `uint8_t`.  Ya rly.  You have to write functions to explicitly convert between the in-memory representation and the on-disk representation.  These are also a good place to do any checking that may be necessary, and deal with endianness.

Worked example for your BmpFileHeader:

```
// Fixed fields not represented in in-memory header.
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t filesize;     // total size of file in bytes
    uint32_t headerOffset; // offset from beginning of file to end of headers
                           // (normally 54)
} BmpFileHeader;

#define BMP_FILE_HEADER_MAGIC_1  0
#define BMP_FILE_HEADER_MAGIC_2  1
#define BMP_FILE_HEADER_FILESIZE 2
#define BMP_FILE_HEADER_RESERVED 6
#define BMP_FILE_HEADER_HDROFF   10
#define BMP_FILE_HEADER_SIZE     14
typedef uint8_t BmpFileHeaderOnDisk[BMP_FILE_HEADER_SIZE];

uint32_t
le32_to_cpu(uint8_t *p)
{
    return ((((uint32_t)p[0]) <<  0) | 
            (((uint32_t)p[1]) <<  8) |
            (((uint32_t)p[2]) << 16) |
            (((uint32_t)p[3]) << 24));
}

// Returns true if header is successfully parsed.
bool
load_bmp_file_header(BmpFileHeaderOnDisk ondisk, BmpFileHeader *inmem)
{
    if (ondisk[BMP_FILE_HEADER_MAGIC_1] != 'B' ||
        ondisk[BMP_FILE_HEADER_MAGIC_2] != 'M' ||
        le32_to_cpu(ondisk + BMP_FILE_HEADER_RESERVED) != 0)
        return false; // not a BMP file

    inmem->filesize = le32_to_cpu(ondisk + BMP_FILE_HEADER_FILESIZE);
    inmem->headerOffset = le32_to_cpu(ondisk + BMP_FILE_HEADER_HDROFF);
    return true;
}
```

Going the opposite way, and the treatment of the "info" header, left as exercises.

Comment: Wow, thank you, this gives me a lot to think about. I have always had a love-hate relationship with bitwise operators. Is code like this less resource consuming than doing it via structs?

Comment: Code like this is *correct* (assuming I didn't make a mistake, anyway), and code that attempts to "do it via structs" is *incorrect*; resource consumption is moot.

Comment: Understood. One more question, if permitted: for the reverse, I would still use the regular fwrite() function, just in uint8 steps?

Comment: For the reverse, you write a function `store_bmp_file_header` that converts from `BmpFileHeader` back to `BmpFileHeaderOnDisk`, and then you apply `fwrite` to the `BmpFileHeaderOnDisk`, with `size=1,nmemb=BMP_FILE_HEADER_SIZE`.  It is *always* best to call `fwrite` with its `size` argument set to 1 and its `nmemb` argument set to the size in bytes of whatever you want to write -- otherwise you cannot recover from short writes.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea of portable file parsing is to view a file as a stream of bytes (type `signed char` or `unsigned char`) and only as that. You shouldn't try to superimpose a `struct` or other types over these bytes as this will make your code unportable; after all, structure layouts, byte order and many other things that can affect how data is represented are platform dependent.

A good idea is to define functions like these; if you fear that they are not efficient enough, provide them as `static inline` functions in the translation unit that uses them.

```
/* portably read a 32 bit unsigned int in little-endian representation */
static uint32_t
read_le32(const unsigned char buf[4])
{
    uint32_t result;

    result  = (buf[0] & 0xff) <<  0;
    result |= (buf[1] & 0xff) <<  8;
    result |= (buf[2] & 0xff) << 16;
    result |= (buf[3] & 0xff) << 24;

    return (result);
}
```

and similarily for a 16-bit unsigned int:

```
static uint16_t
read_le16(const unsigned char buf[4])
{

    return (buf[0] & 0xff) | (buf[1] & 0xff) << 8;
}
```

Now you can read in headers like this:

```
static void
read_bitmap_header(bitmapHead *bfh, const unsigned char buf[56])
{

    bfh->fileheader.typeSignature =  read_le16(buf +  0);
    bfh->fileheader.filesize =       read_le32(buf +  2);
    bfh->fileheader.reserved =       read_le32(buf +  6);
    bfh->fileheader.headerOffset =   read_le32(buf + 10);
    bfh->infoheader.infoHeaderSize = read_le32(buf + 14);
    bfh->infoheader.Width =          read_le32(buf + 18);
    /* ... */
}
```

This looks really cumbersome at first, but actually this approach is very clear and leads to highly portable code.

Comment: I believe you have a bug in your read_le32 function.  The bitwise shift operations have a higher operator precedence.  You are bitshifting 0xff and then the bitwise AND operation on the char yields 0.

Comment: @DavidPisani Oh right. I looked at the [precedence table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) specifically to catch this, but I have managed to do it the wrong way right. Will be fixed in a second.

Answer (score 1):

You want to specify an attribute type for your `struct` as packed.  See the GCC document on [attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).  Specifically you want to use the `__packed__` attribute.  The `__packed__` attribute minimizes the memory requirements needed for your `struct`.
An example of using the `__packed__` attribute for your `BmpFileHeader` is as so,

```
typedef struct
{
  uint16_t typeSignature; // = "BM"
  uint32_t filesize;     //filesize in Bytes
  uint32_t reserved;     // = 0 for this program
  uint32_t headerOffset; // = 54
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BmpFileHeader;
```

You can use the same methodology in your other `struct` data structures.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this! Is there a way to circumvent this issue to make it work with all C compilers?

Comment: @BigBadWolf Padding is implementation defined. To make your code portable, to not try to make your struct equal to the file header; you will not be able to do this. Instead manually marshall the file format into a struct.

Comment: If you like, I can add another answer describing possible approaches.

Comment: That would be amazing, yes! I really want to know how to do this so it is portable.

Comment: Also, the `__attribute__((__packed__))` syntax isn't standard, other compilers don't implement it. Also, this will not work on big-endian platforms.

Comment: I agree with FUZxxl.  It does pose some problems.  He stated he was using GCC so I gave a solution using it.  I can give an answer for portability that works independent of endianness, but that will take some more time on my part.  If you have an example ready FUZxxl please share.

Answer (score 0):

Use pragma pack;

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
// your typedef structs
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Example;

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct
{
  uint16_t typeSignature; // = "BM"
  uint32_t filesize;     //filesize in Bytes
  uint32_t reserved;     // = 0 for this program
  uint32_t headerOffset; // = 54
} BmpFileHeader;

typedef struct
{
  uint32_t infoHeaderSize;    //size of header in byte. ( = 40)
  uint32_t Width;             //width of file in pixels
  uint32_t Height;            // height of file in pixels

  uint16_t Colors;       //colorbits per pixel (24 for 3byte RGB)
  uint16_t bitsPerPixel;
  uint32_t Compression;       //compression mode; 0 for uncompressed.
  uint32_t SizeImg;         //if biCompress = 0, =0. Else: filesize.

  uint32_t xPelsPerMeter;     // for output device;
  uint32_t yPelsPerMeter;     // 0 for this program

  uint32_t ColorsUsed;      // Colours used; = 0 for all
  uint32_t ColorsImportant; // num. of used colours, 0 for all
} BmpInfoHeader;

typedef struct
{
  BmpFileHeader fileheader;
  BmpInfoHeader infoheader;
} bitmapHead; // now you will get sizeof = 54
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Here is a complete hello world;

#### Demo Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct
{
  uint16_t typeSignature; // = "BM"
  uint32_t filesize;     //filesize in Bytes
  uint32_t reserved;     // = 0 for this program
  uint32_t headerOffset; // = 54
} BmpFileHeader;

typedef struct
{
  uint32_t infoHeaderSize;    //size of header in byte. ( = 40)
  uint32_t Width;             //width of file in pixels
  uint32_t Height;            // height of file in pixels

  uint16_t Colors;       //colorbits per pixel (24 for 3byte RGB)
  uint16_t bitsPerPixel;
  uint32_t Compression;       //compression mode; 0 for uncompressed.
  uint32_t SizeImg;         //if biCompress = 0, =0. Else: filesize.

  uint32_t xPelsPerMeter;     // for output device;
  uint32_t yPelsPerMeter;     // 0 for this program

  uint32_t ColorsUsed;      // Colours used; = 0 for all
  uint32_t ColorsImportant; // num. of used colours, 0 for all
} BmpInfoHeader;

typedef struct
{
  BmpFileHeader fileheader;
  BmpInfoHeader infoheader;
} bitmapHead; // now you will get sizeof = 54
#pragma pack(pop)

int main()
{
    printf("Size of bitmapHead : %d\n", sizeof(bitmapHead));
}
```

#### Demo Output

```
>pragmaExample
Size of bitmapHead : 54
```